# Create Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard style selection

Tags: c#, mouse

I'm making an application relating to key bindings - hence I wish to take an image of a mouse, and overlay a outline of button on said mouse to show the key (I also wish to do this with controllers and keyboard, but it should be the same as doing it with the mouse)

Effectively, I'm going for something akin to the Microsoft Mouse and Keyboard program:

[image]

The mouse cursor cannot be seen in that image, but its over the right mouse button - hence its selected / highlighted both the whole button and its binding.

I understand C# / Visual Studio might not be the best way to do this. However I'm not really wanting anything majorly fancy. In fact, being able to overlay one image over the other and detect the mouse over would be fine.

What's a good way, or even just a way I can do this, preferably without having to code it directly? ( I.e being able to place and position it in the designer, then coding its visibility and all the rest )

I have tried to use the Visual Basic Powerpacks graphics, however they only seem to offer basic pre-defined shapes (in this case I used rectangles) and thus they looked out of place when put on top of the mouse buttons

I have also tried using a image box with 2 images (as per Hans Passant's suggestion) however I could not get the image box to take into account the transparency of the image

Comment: No I don't think I need Java, I said I considered that. But I see your point ok, I'll edit that out. I was unaware the image boxes took the transparency of their image into account when handling mouse events. Thanks I'll give that a try now

Comment: @Hans Passant I have now updated the question, to which I hope is now at a better standard. I have also tried your suggestion, and found - As I suspected - didn't work

Comment: Hi, I updated my orginal answer, so that it covers also a pixel perfect mouse detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PictureBoxes. You can place them at design time, and they have events for mouse over, click etc. On a specific mouse action change the image of it. In this example i just set it to null, but you get the idea:

```
    Image picImage = null;  // to store original image     

    private void pictureBox1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = picImage;   // rest original image
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        picImage = pictureBox1.Image;   // remember the original image
        pictureBox1.Image = null;   // change the current image
    }
```

Update:

Ok, to have a pixel perfect selection just use two PictureBoxes in the same location, one showing the unselected image (pictureBox1), one showing the selected image (pictureBox2). Make pictureBox1 invisible. Then use this code to show/hide them when your mouse hovers over transparent/nontransparent areas of the image:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    Color color = b.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);

    if (color.A != 0)
    {
        pictureBox1.Visible = false;
        pictureBox2.Visible = true;
    }
}

private void pictureBox2_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image);
    Color color = b.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);

    if (color.A == 0)
    {
        pictureBox2.Visible = false;
        pictureBox1.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do the mouse events "wrap" around the image? I was thinking they just were a fixed square that the image filled, hence the mouse events would go off depending on the square, regardless of the colors of the image itself

Comment: no, the mouse events would recognize just the squares of the pictureboxes. But the code covered in the update part of my answer checks for the exact measurements of the nontransparent areas of the image.

Comment: Works great, except for two things: The first I have put as an edit to your answer - It fixes an error caused by the mouse leaving the imagebox at the bottom. The second is that it wont "unselect" if you move the mouse off the button in an area not white. This can be fixed by having something behind the button with an event that resets the two deselect + select buttons

Comment: You could use the MouseLeave event of pictureBox2 to reset the visibility.

Comment: I tired this, but it didn't work - the box would not become visible, I think because the event was being called incorrectly

Comment: I have no problems with it. I implemented it like: private void pictureBox2_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBox2.Visible = false;
            pictureBox1.Visible = true;
        }